# Helm install or upgrade release failed on Kubernetes cluster: the server could not find the requested resource or UPGRADE FAILED: no deployed releases

Tags: kubernetes, devops, kubernetes-helm

Using helm for deploying chart on my Kubernetes cluster, since one day, I can't deploy a new one or upgrading one existed.

Indeed, each time I am using helm I have an error message telling me that it is not possible to install or upgrade ressources.

If I run `helm install --name foo . -f values.yaml --namespace foo-namespace` I have this output:

> Error: release foo failed: the server could not find the requested
>   resource

If I run `helm upgrade --install foo . -f values.yaml --namespace foo-namespace` or `helm upgrade foo . -f values.yaml --namespace foo-namespace` I have this error:

> Error: UPGRADE FAILED: "foo" has no deployed releases

I don't really understand why.

This is my helm version:

```
Client: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.12.3", GitCommit:"eecf22f77df5f65c823aacd2dbd30ae6c65f186e", GitTreeState:"clean"}
Server: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.12.3", GitCommit:"eecf22f77df5f65c823aacd2dbd30ae6c65f186e", GitTreeState:"clean"}
```

On my kubernetes cluster I have tiller deployed with the same version, when I run `kubectl describe pods tiller-deploy-84b... -n kube-system`:

```
Name:               tiller-deploy-84b8...
Namespace:          kube-system
Priority:           0
PriorityClassName:  <none>
Node:               k8s-worker-1/167.114.249.216
Start Time:         Tue, 26 Feb 2019 10:50:21 +0100
Labels:             app=helm
                    name=tiller
                    pod-template-hash=84b...
Annotations:        <none>
Status:             Running
IP:                 <IP_NUMBER>
Controlled By:      ReplicaSet/tiller-deploy-84b8...
Containers:
  tiller:
    Container ID:   docker://0302f9957d5d83db22...
    Image:          gcr.io/kubernetes-helm/tiller:v2.12.3
    Image ID:       docker-pullable://gcr.io/kubernetes-helm/tiller@sha256:cab750b402d24d...
    Ports:          44134/TCP, 44135/TCP
    Host Ports:     0/TCP, 0/TCP
    State:          Running
      Started:      Tue, 26 Feb 2019 10:50:28 +0100
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Liveness:       http-get http://:44135/liveness delay=1s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Readiness:      http-get http://:44135/readiness delay=1s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Environment:
      TILLER_NAMESPACE:    kube-system
      TILLER_HISTORY_MAX:  0
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from helm-token-... (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             True 
  ContainersReady   True 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  helm-token-...:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  helm-token-...
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:
  Type    Reason     Age   From                   Message
  ----    ------     ----  ----                   -------
  Normal  Scheduled  26m   default-scheduler      Successfully assigned kube-system/tiller-deploy-84b86cbc59-kxjqv to worker-1
  Normal  Pulling    26m   kubelet, k8s-worker-1  pulling image "gcr.io/kubernetes-helm/tiller:v2.12.3"
  Normal  Pulled     26m   kubelet, k8s-worker-1  Successfully pulled image "gcr.io/kubernetes-helm/tiller:v2.12.3"
  Normal  Created    26m   kubelet, k8s-worker-1  Created container
  Normal  Started    26m   kubelet, k8s-worker-1  Started container
```

Is someone have faced the same issue ?

---

Update:

This the folder structure of my actual chart named foo:
structure folder of the chart:

```
> templates/
  > deployment.yaml 
  > ingress.yaml
  > service.yaml
> .helmignore
> Chart.yaml 
> values.yaml
```

I have already tried to delete the chart in failure using the delete command `helm del --purge foo` but the same errors occurred.

Just to be more precise, the chart foo is in fact a custom chart using my own private registry. ImagePullSecret are normally setting up.

I have run these two commands `helm upgrade foo . -f values.yaml --namespace foo-namespace --force` | `helm upgrade --install foo . -f values.yaml --namespace foo-namespace --force` and I still get an error:

```
UPGRADE FAILED
ROLLING BACK
Error: failed to create resource: the server could not find the requested resource
Error: UPGRADE FAILED: failed to create resource: the server could not find the requested resource
```

Notice that foo-namespace already exist. So the error don't come from the namespace name or the namespace itself. Indeed, if I run `helm list`, I can see that the **foo** chart is in a `FAILED` status.

Comment: `helm del --purge foo` is a little bit of a blunt hammer, but it makes Helm actually forget about everything it knows about the release and sometimes helps this kind of problem.

Comment: can you show the directory structure from where you are trying to run `$ helm install ...` or `$ helm upgrage ...`?

Comment: Does `foo-namespace` namespace exist?

Comment: @AnnaSlastnikova yes, the foo namespace exist, the error does not come from this part (typo or anything about the namespace itself)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Tiller stores all releases as ConfigMaps in Tiller's namespace(`kube-system` in your case). Try to find broken release and delete it's ConfigMap using commands:

```
$ kubectl get cm --all-namespaces -l OWNER=TILLER
NAMESPACE     NAME               DATA   AGE
kube-system   nginx-ingress.v1   1      22h

$ kubectl delete cm  nginx-ingress.v1 -n kube-system
```

Next, delete all release objects (deployment,services,ingress, etc) manually and reinstall release using helm again.

If it didn't help, you may try to download newer [release](https://github.com/helm/helm/releases) of Helm (v2.14.3 at the moment) and update/reinstall Tiller.

Comment: did not help for me, I use helm 2.14.3 and even try on a new k8s cluster with "failed to create resource: the server could not find the requested resource". As this only happens with this deployment how may I find out what resource could not be found?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, but cleanup did not help also try the same helm chart on a brand new k8s cluster did not help.

So I found out that there was a missing apiVersion caused the problem. I found it out by doing a

```
helm install xyz --dry-run
```

copy the output to a new *test.yaml* file and use

```
kubectl apply test.yaml
```

there I see the error (apiVersion line was moved to a comment line)

Comment: it's not working for me admin1@POC-k8s-master:~$ helm install xyz --dry-run
Error: failed to download "xyz" (hint: running `helm repo update` may help)
admin1@POC-k8s-master:~$ helm repo update
Hang tight while we grab the latest from your chart repositories...
...Skip local chart repository
...Successfully got an update from the "stable" chart repository
Update Complete. ⎈ Happy Helming!⎈
admin1@POC-k8s-master:~$ helm install prometheus --dry-run
Error: failed to download "prometheus" (hint: running `helm repo update` may help)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but not due to broken releases. **After upgrading helm.** It seems newer versions of helm do bad with the `--wait` parameter. So for anyone facing the same issue: Just removing `--wait`, and leave `--debug` from `helm upgrade` parameters solved my issue.

Comment: admin1@POC-k8s-master:~/.helm$ helm init --wait
$HELM_HOME has been configured at /home/admin1/.helm.
Error: error installing: the server could not find the requested resource

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when I tried to deploy custom chart with CronJob instead deployment. [The error](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/cluster-integration/auto-deploy-image/-/blob/master/src/bin/auto-deploy#L287) occurs on this step in deploy script. To resolve it need to add ENV Variable `ROLLOUT_STATUS_DISABLED=true` it is solved in [this issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/merge_requests/28130).