# chart metadata (Chart.yaml) missing on helm upgrade

Tags: kubernetes, airflow, kubernetes-helm, minikube

I was following this [blog post](https://towardsdatascience.com/kubernetesexecutor-for-airflow-e2155e0f909c) and at this command,

`helm upgrade --install airflow airflow/ \
    --namespace airflow \
    --values values.yaml`

I got this error. 
`in airflow: chart metadata (Chart.yaml) missing` but I actually have the Chart.yaml file under `airflow/`.

```sh
$ ls
Chart.yaml      charts          requirements.yaml   tiller.yaml
Icon?           requirements.lock   templates       values.yaml
```

helm version & kubectl pod below

```
$ helm version
Client: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.13.1", GitCommit:"618447cbf203d147601b4b9bd7f8c37a5d39fbb4", GitTreeState:"clean"}
Server: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.13.1", GitCommit:"618447cbf203d147601b4b9bd7f8c37a5d39fbb4", GitTreeState:"clean"}
```

```
$ kubectl get pods --namespace kube-system
NAME                                    READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
coredns-fb8b8dccf-9z8v5                 1/1       Running   3          6h
coredns-fb8b8dccf-wdtpl                 1/1       Running   3          6h
etcd-minikube                           1/1       Running   1          6h
kube-addon-manager-minikube             1/1       Running   1          6h
kube-apiserver-minikube                 1/1       Running   1          6h
kube-controller-manager-minikube        1/1       Running   1          6h
kube-proxy-m4whq                        1/1       Running   0          2h
kube-scheduler-minikube                 1/1       Running   1          6h
kubernetes-dashboard-79dd6bfc48-5z9cx   1/1       Running   3          6h
storage-provisioner                     1/1       Running   3          6h
tiller-deploy-8458f6c667-wmv62          1/1       Running   1          4h
```

Could someone help to fix it?

Answer (score 5):

I also had the error with Airflow. I noticed that you have to respect the folder structure. This example will fail:

```
./charts
  ./charts/airflow
  ./charts/template ---> will produce the error
```

While this folder structure will work:

```
./charts
   ./charts/airflow 
   templates --> will work
```

Answer (score 5):

The directory must not contain a directory with the same name as the chart name.

For anyone stumbling on this, the answer is over here: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-helm/issues/735#issuecomment-828779466

Comment: jidckii, a link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)

Answer (score 4):

detailed information about helm upgrade and requirements you can find [here](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/master/docs/helm/helm_upgrade.md):

In your example please go to airflow-kube-helm directory and run:

```
helm upgrade --install airflow ./airflow/ --namespace airflow --values ./airflow/values.yaml
```

In case the previously deployment failed, please use `helm delete (your_release_name) --purge`
More info about this issue [here](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/3208#issuecomment-348154521) and [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/54760)

Hope this help. Please share with your findings.

Comment: Thanks for the help :) But I' still getting the same error with additional comment. 
---
Release "airflow" does not exist. Installing it now.
 in airflow: chart metadata (Chart.yaml) missing
---

Comment: Could you please try with __--force__ option?

Comment: Thanks again! But --force still gives me same error.. I realized that the blog post didn't run `helm install` command but it doesn't relate to the issue?

Comment: In the post there is an option "upgrade --install" in that case "if a release by this name doesn't already exist, run an install". Could you please check helm was properly installed "helm version" and "kubectl get pods --namespace kube-system" if your tiller is in runnings state?

Comment: Ah I see, understood. Thanks a lot! I updated my questions with outputs of these two command.

Comment: when you got an error  "--- Release "airflow" does not exist. Installing it now" What is the output of "helm ls"

Comment: After the error, `helm ls` doesn't output anything.

Comment: can you run and see maybe it's in FAILED status ? 

   helm ls --all

Comment: It still doesn't output anything with `helm ls --all` :(

Comment: Could you please verify the status of your cluster. It seems you have more issues -- as we can see all pods were restarted more than once, even tiller.
Could you please also verify your $HELM_HOME path. After all you can try to install and upgrade another chart?

At least please remove your deployment, reinstall Helm tiller - for deployment please use last stable release.
It seems there's no release which we can cleanly upgrade from.
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54883258/helm-install-or-upgrade-release-failed-on-kubernetes-cluster-the-server-could-n)

Comment: I think you are missing the chart dir. it could be something like: `helm upgrade --install --version x.x.x -f  ~/path/to/values/values.yaml  <release_name> ./<chart_dir>`

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue when trying to install Ingress Nginx using Helm.

For me I put the helm commands in a script called `install.sh`, however, I was not running the file within the folder where the `install.sh` script.

I was running it this way `sh ingress-nginx/install.sh`, and it was returning the error.

All I had to do was `cd` into the folder and run the script:

```
cd sh ingress-nginx
sh install.sh
```

And it ran successfully this time.